# Cannot upload file to google drive using service account

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use service account of goolge drive api to upload the file to 'my' central Google Drive. 
I get the sample code from the Google drive API, however, when I run the code, exactly, when insert file into drive using Google_DriveService, the Google chrome show that "This webpage is not available".
Here is my php code:

```
<?php

require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
session_start();

/**
 * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts.
 *
 * @return Google_DriveService service object.
 */
function buildService() {

    $DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<email>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '<filename>.p12';
  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}

function uploadFile($service, $mime, $src) {
    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    $file->setMimeType($mime);
    $data = file_get_contents($src);

    try {
    //ERROR HERE: cannot insert (upload) file
        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file,
            array(
                'data' => $data,
                'mimeType' => $mime,
                'convert' => true,
            )
        );

        return $createdFile;    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }   
}

//test upload file to server
$service =buildService();
$mineType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
$path = "toupload.docx";
$file = uploadFile($service,$mineType, $path);

?>
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: This is the message from google chrome, not from google drive server This webpage is not available
The connection to 114.30.45.25 was interrupted.
Here are some suggestions:................
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

Comment: If you can var_dump($e), it could be helpful. Browser's message is the default for http 500.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot var_dump($e) :( Have you tried Google drive api before? Do I need to add the code to make client grant access to their drive?

Comment: I also tried the delegation of google apps domain, but still got the same error

Comment: Yea, I work for Google Drive and your code looks fine to me. It's impossible to say anything without the error message. Are you sure that certificate file is not corrupted?

Comment: I have tried another service account but still does not work. By the way, you can review the code of my demo here: http://114.30.45.25/serviceAccount/ Thank you.